# Programmatically getting Eclipse preference value

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, preferences

What is the best way to use preference values defined in plugin code? For example, I have created a custom editor(multipage) and would like to use Text font preference value which is already defined in eclipse.

[image]

Code sample would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This varies a lot depending on which preference you want to get.

For the standard fonts you should use `JFaceResources`:

```java
Font textFont = JFaceResources.getFont(JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are many preferences contributed by plugins. How do I get thier preference store and how do I know what preference name/id to use to retrieve their values? My question was one of those examples. Looking at the attached image, esp. Text Font, how can I get the value of that specific preference?

Comment: There is no general way. The fonts preferences are stored in the workbench theme registry which is not available as an API, some in other registries or in the Eclipse preferences store. What way do you want to use the Text Font setting that requires something other than a Font?

Comment: I thought there would be a general way to figure out stores and get values from them. Since I have UI pages in my multi-page editor plugin, I wanted to use the existing preferences instead of building a new page. But if that is that case as you mentioned, I will use your suggestion(code). Does that line of code get a value of Text font preference in the image attached?

Comment: Yes it uses the value from the preference. If you want to define fonts use the `org.eclipse.ui.fontDefinitions` extension point to add them to the Colors and Fonts preference page and access via JFaceResources.